# Garbage Collector para C++

Tags: c++, gerenciamento-de-memória, garbage-collector

Eu entendo claramente o que é e para que serve um Garbage Collector. Ele é muito conhecido em Java.

Existe alguma biblioteca em C++ que implemente o GC ou que corrija *memory leaks*?

Já procurei pela internet mas sempre resulta em C++ para o Visual Studio, o que não me é útil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe o [C++/CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=vs-2019) da Microsoft. Ele não é o C++ padrão, mas usa o mesmo GC no C#.

Algumas pessoas consideram que o uso adequado dos [ponteiros inteligentes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=vs-2019) não deixa de ser um uma forma de GC. Outras acham que não é bem o caso, apesar de ambos gerenciarem a memória de forma automática. É compreensível que esta forma seja um pouco mais limitada, mas funciona muito bem se souber o que está fazendo.

Além disso, bibliotecas podem ser usas para ajudar neste aspecto. As versões mais novas do C++ padrão vêm especificando maneiras de facilitar o desenvolvimento de GCs mais complexos para uso opcional, mas até onde sei não há nada muito bom para uso ainda e parece que não haverá, é uma dessas coisas que caíram no esquecimento. Hoje não é fácil fazer um GC para C++, a linguagem não ajuda.

Existem GCs conservadores que ajudam, mas causam tanto vazamento que se tornam inviáveis na maior parte dos casos. O mais conhecido é o [Boehm](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/).

Se não souber o que está fazendo mesmo com GC há vazamento de memória, em qualquer linguagem. Você não tem ideia da quantidade de aplicação que possuem vazamentos e ninguém percebe. Normalmente fica perceptível só quando o vazamento é muito grave (comum em C/C++) e quando o aplicação roda por muito tempo, o que é incomum em casos de outras linguagens.

- [Mais detalhes sobre o problema](http://www.iecc.com/gclist/GC-faq.html).
- Um [exemplo de GC para C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/912/A-garbage-collection-framework-for-C). Tem sérias restrições. Desconheço a qualidade.
- [GC generacional](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1669/A-Generational-Garbage-Collector-in-C). Há limitações também. Desconheço a qualidade.

Se realmente acha que o GC pode ajudar de forma fundamental, considere fortemente usar outra linguagem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado! Os links ajudaram bastante