# Tem diferença entre C++ do GCC e o C++ do Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio, gcc

Já programei em C++ compilando com o GCC e quando comecei a usar o Visual Studio notei que ele tem suporte para C++, porém a implementação é voltada para a plataforma .Net.

Existe diferença entre essas duas versões de C++ em questão de tempo de programação, velocidades de processamento etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existem dois C++ no Visual Studio. O baseado no .NET é o C++/CLI, embora ainda seja muito parecido com C++, não segue o padrão da linguagem. Na verdade ele é [usado apenas para facilitar a comunicação de código .NET com código nativo C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69742/101). Só para citar exemplos de diferença [ele usa um *garbage collector*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103810/101) e não permite herança múltipla.

Já o C++ nativo que também está presente é [conforme com o ISO](https://isocpp.org/) e é essencialmente o mesmo do GCC. Claro que há algumas diferenças de implementação onde o padrão deixa isso em aberto, onde sejam claras extensões e onde cada um prioriza. O [GCC pode ter algumas funções do novo padrão](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) ([C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17)) ou até do oficial ([C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14)) que o [Visual C++ não suporta ainda, mais vai suportar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh567368(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), e vice-versa (agora C++ 14 o VS já suporta tudo, acho que tudo do C++17 também e até do C++20 estava bem adiantado quando editei aqui, esperemos o C++23). São poucas coisas, mas é bom consultar antes de usar as últimas novidades. No resto é igual. Um código escrito para um deve funcionar no outro, se tomado alguns devidos cuidados.

Obviamente que cada um pode ter suas próprias otimizações e funcionalidades, desde que interprete o código padrão e gere o mesmo modelo de binário atendendo os requisitos estabelecidos no padrão. As ferramentas disponíveis para cada um são bem diferentes.

[Tabela comparativa](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

Entenda [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101)